# Convertir Variable JS a PHP

Tags: sql-server, php7, fpdf

Tengo este problema tengo esta variable JS de esta manera:

```javascript
let setear = tinymce.get("mensaje").setContent($datos[0]["Contenido"]);
```

El contenido de esa variable de acuerdo a la documentación del editor *Tinymce* me va setear el contenido que esta guardado en formato *HTML* como *string* del campo de la *BD* y lo he intentado y no lo he logrado, es convertir esa variable *JS* a *PHP*

Estoy usando la libreria *FPDF* y quiero pasar esa variable *JS* al archivo *PHP* donde genero el *PDF*. El proceso es asi: hago clic en el boton imprimir y me genera el archivo *pdf* de los datos que estan en el campo que se llama `Contenido` de la *BD*

**Código *JS* de la funcion *imprimir***

```javascript
function Imprimir(id) {
  $('#modalconsulta').modal('show'); 
  $("#divreporte").html('<div class="video-container">  <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="reporteMemo.php?num='+id+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>');
}
```

**Código *PHP* que genera el *PDF***

```php
$q = "SELECT TB_Memo.ID_Memo, TB_Memo.Fecha_Creacion, a.Nombres +' '+ a.Apellidos as Destinatarios, b.Nombres + ' ' + b.Apellidos as Remitente, TB_Memo.Asunto, TB_Memo.Contenido, TB_Memo.ID_TipoMemo, TB_Memo.ID_EstadoMemo, TB_Memo.Fecha_Envio, a.ID_Empleado as IEM1, b.ID_Empleado as IEM2, TB_Memo.ID_Memorandum
    from TB_Memo
    inner join TB_Destinatario on TB_Memo.ID_Memo = TB_Destinatario.ID_Memo
    inner join TB_Remitente on TB_Memo.ID_Memo = TB_Remitente.ID_Memo
    inner join [IHTT_RRHH].[dbo].[TB_Empleados] a on TB_Destinatario.ID_Empleado = a.ID_Empleado
    inner join [IHTT_RRHH].[dbo].[TB_Empleados] b on TB_Remitente.ID_Empleado = b.ID_Empleado 
    WHERE TB_Memo.ID_Memo = :ID";

$datos = select($q,array(':ID'=> $_GET['num'] ));

$pdf->MultiCell(0,6,html_entity_decode(($datos[0]["Contenido"]), ENT_COMPAT),0,1) ;
```

**Código *HTML* donde uso el editor *Tinymce***

```html
<textarea  id="mensaje" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
```